# Copy complete git repository over airgap

Tags: git

I need to migrate a git repo (code + history) from machine A/server A to machine B/server B with no communication between A and B.

I'm not sure what is the right way to do it:

- git archive ?
- git bundle ?
- git clone + git remote add ?

Could you please help me with the best way to do it ?

**EDIT**

For the record I followed this procedure
https://gist.github.com/xtream1101/fd79f3099f572967605fab24d976b179

On machine A

```
git clone --mirror git@my_repo_A.git
cd my_repo_A.git
git bundle create ../my_repo_A.bundle --all
```

Copy my_repo_A.bundle on USB stick to machine B
Create empty repo my_repo_B on server B
On machine B

```
git clone my_repo_A.bundle
cd my_repo_A
git remote set-url origin git@my_repo_B.git
git push --all
git push --tags
```

This seems to do the job !

Comment: No **direct** communication, or none at all?

Comment: git bundle sounds like it.... if you can use a transfer medium (a USB drive or so) you could just clone the repo into the USB key and put it on the other computer.

Comment: no direct communication, I'll have to use a USB drive indeed

Comment: What about just copying the `.git` directory?

Comment: is this the way to do it ?  https://gist.github.com/xtream1101/fd79f3099f572967605fab24d976b179